Spock temporary directories in data-driven test fail after first case
I am using Spock to test some code (Spring app) that involved saving data to disk. I need to test more than one case, so I am using where: keyword to plan multiple test cases. The tested code saves some data into tempDir, then moves that into dataDir.
Somehow, no matter how I try to configure the temporary directories, either by @TempDir or Files.createTempDirectory(), the first test passes fine, and the second fails, as the temporary Path is null. If I comment out any of the cases, the other one passes.
It might be important to note that the tempDir seems fine, the test always fails due to the dataSavedDir being null.
My test spec:
class SimulationStorageSpec extends Specification implements StorageDtos, AsyncTestUtils {

    SimulationStorageService service
    @TempDir Path tempDir
    @TempDir Path dataDir
    @Shared String simulationId = "ABC123"

    def setup() {
        service = new SimulationStorageConfiguration().simulationDataStorageService(tempDir.toString(), dataDir.toString())
    }

    def "should accept raw simulation data file and save it"() {
        when:
        service.processAttachment(datafile, dto)
        then:
        Path dataSavedDir = dataDir.resolve("simulations/${simulationId}/${directoryName}")
        awaitUntil(!isEmpty(tempDir), "File exists in a tempDir")
                .andThen(!isEmpty(dataSavedDir), "File exists in an appropriate directory of a simulation")
                .andThen(isEmpty(tempDir), "tempDir is empty")
        and:
        try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(dataSavedDir.toFile().listFiles()[0].toPath())) {
            assert DigestUtils.sha256Hex(is) == dto.getFileHash()
        }
        where:
        datafile                    | dto                                   | directoryName
        singleRawPlotData()         | singleRawPlotDto(simulationId)        | "plots"
        singleRawGeometryData()     | singleRawGeometryDto(simulationId)    | "geometry"
    }

AsyncTestUtils (just a trait to chain PollingConditions, the tested code is asynchronous):
trait AsyncTestUtils <T extends AsyncTestUtils<T>> {
    PollingConditions pollingConditions = new PollingConditions()

    T awaitUntil(Boolean condition, String failMessage = "Assertion failed in awaitUntil") {
        pollingConditions.within(10) {
            assert condition : failMessage
        }
        return (T) this
    }

    T andThen(Boolean condition, String failMessage = "Assertion failed in andThen") {
        pollingConditions.within(10) {
            assert condition : failMessage
        }
        return (T) this
    }
}

Could this be a problem with temporary directory config, my async testing code or something else?

Shouldn't the "condtion" be a closure/function/lambda/... that will be called inside the within blocks? Right now the result is already determined the moment the work begins?

I might be wrong since these Groovy features are rather new to me, but the code checks for the tempDir being non-empty and later on being empty, can this even be predetermined? Also, each case works if the other one is commented out.

While @cfrick correctly identified a mistake in my testing code, the problem lied in over-asserting my test.
The assertion happened after service.processAttachment() returned, but this method only saved a file into temp directory and left rest of the processing to the new job in the executor. The Spock test then probably raced the job to assert existence of the file in the temp directory, and if the job was faster to move the file, the test failed. Removal of the first assertion led to the test passing 100% of the time and equally checking the logic.

The functions in the trait accepts a boolean value:
T awaitUntil(Boolean condition, String failMessage = "Assertion failed in awaitUntil") {
//           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    pollingConditions.within(10) {
        assert condition : failMessage
    }
    return (T) this
}

And they are called like:
awaitUntil(!isEmpty(tempDir), "File exists in a tempDir")
//         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

So this is just passing a boolean result; the "assertion"
here is done before calling awaitUntil.
So the result is already pre-determined; waiting for this
result/assertion is useless.  It will either always work at once or never work.
So what you want here is to pass a "boolean supplier" instead.  With
groovy the most convenient way is passing a closure:
// call passing the thing to check
awaitUntil({!isEmpty(tempDir)}, "File exists in a tempDir")
// accept a function and call it in the `assert`
T awaitUntil(Closure<Boolean> conditionFn, String failMessage = "Assertion failed in awaitUntil") {
    pollingConditions.within(10) {
        assert conditionFn() : failMessage
    }
    return (T) this
}


Thanks! There is certainly an improvement, but the solution isn't final yet, or at least to the main problem I have posed - the test passes both cases most of the time, but far from 100%.
The error should be easier to find using your improved assertions though. It appears like the first assertion fails, which is the most basic file save. Spock docs says that the iterations/cases are entirely isolated, but I suspect that the directories are not.

The problem with your question is that it does not constitute an MCVE. Whatever Spock "isolates", we have no way of knowing what your code does to "unisolate" it, i.e. how the specifications themselves and the code under specification use the shared resources you seem to be struggling with. My working hypothesis for now is that not Spock but your usage of it is probably the problem. This assumption could be wrong, of course, but without an MCVE I have no way of knowing for sure.

@kriegaex This is a fair point, I struggled with producing a MCVE simple enough that it isn't one of those questions with absurd wall of code that people don't bother reading. Your suggestion is likely correct. I am not able to confirm it 100%, but 99% the issue was that I saved the temp file in a temp directory and then sent a job to an executor and returned a CompleteableFuture. Upon this, there was probably a race between the Spock to assert its existence and the executed job to pick up the file and move it into proper directory.

While @cfrick 's answer is helpful and exposes a mistake in my code, I don't know if I should accept since it doesn't directly answer my (very, very imperfect I admit) question.

I am happy that you managed to identify the root cause of your problem. As for "wall of code", usually a GitHub repository which everyone can clone easily is a good complement of the sample code in a question. Concerning how to create an MCVE, it is actually a rather mechanical process. Tedious, but no rocket science: You remove bit by bit, shaving off as much code as possible from your original project, until only a minimal reproducer remains. Often, you already understand the problem by isolating it.
